Trying to understand why at the possible constrained extrema points attained with Langrange multiplier method $\nabla f, \nabla g$ are collinear
After some years of studying mathematics, passing all courses with flying colors and reading posts/articles such as:

When using lagrange multipliers why does computing $\nabla f = \lambda \nabla g$ give a mix or a min ( I do not understand the concept entirely)
Why does the method of Lagrange Multipliers fail when $\nabla g =0$?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier
https://medium.com/@andrew.chamberlain/a-simple-explanation-of-why-lagrange-multipliers-works-253e2cdcbf74
https://medium.com/@laineridgway/understand-lagrange-multipliers-and-the-lagrangian-910bbdab6692

I have to say that I honestly still do not understand why the "best possible" value of an objective function $f$ along a constraint curve $g = 0$ is attained at the points (assuming $f$ is $C^1$ along the entire curve $g = 0$) where $\nabla f$ and $\nabla g$ are collinear, i.e. $\nabla f = \lambda \nabla g, \lambda \neq 0$. The usual explanations I have heard or read are that "if $\nabla f \neq \lambda \nabla g$ for any $\lambda \neq 0$, then we could obtain a better value of $f$ by sliding along the curve $g = 0$. Just look at this intuitive picture!".
Question: So perhaps to resolve this problem once and for all, let me first list what I understand and then you could hopefully fill in (or shred to pieces) what I am missing.
We know that:
i.) The gradient of $f$ is perpendicular to its level curves.
ii.) We can only look at the points along the level curve $g = 0$ of $g$.
iii.) If $\nabla f$ exists at all points of $g = 0$, then all critical points $x$ of $f$ on $g = 0$ satisfy $\nabla f(x) = 0$.
iv.) The objective function $f$ can have a continuum of level curves slicing the constraint curve $g = 0$ to small pieces i.e. $f$ can vary a lot on $g = 0$. By i.), $\nabla f$ is perpendicular to all these level curves of $f$ that slice $g = 0$, but need not be collinear with $\nabla g$ on some of them.
As my lack of understanding concerns itself with the non-critical points of $f$ on $g = 0$ which happen to be the best possible points on $g = 0$ given by $\nabla f = \lambda \nabla g, \lambda \neq 0$, let us assume that $\nabla f$ exists and is non-zero on $g = 0$. Thus, if $\nabla f = \lambda \nabla g, \lambda \neq 0$, then $\nabla f$ is pointing at the direction of greatest change of $g$ as imposed by the curve $g = 0$, and by i.) & iv.), at this point $\nabla f$ is perpendicular to some level curve of $f$ that intersects the curve $g = 0$.
And here is where the trail of thought ends: I do not know how to conclude from this that "if $\nabla f$ and $\nabla g$ were not collinear, we could obtain larger/smaller values of $f$ be sliding along $g = 0$ to some other point."

How do you feel about this statement: "If $x^$ is a solution to the constrained optimization problem and $v$ is any tangent vector to the surface $g=0$ at the point $x^$, then $\nabla f(x^)\cdot v = 0$." If such a dot product were nonzero, you could construct a curve passing through $x^$ with tangent vector $v$ such that $f$ increases/decreases. The collinearity result follows directly from this fact

@whpowell96 Hmm, I suppose that is understandable!

Starting from my statement in the comments:
If $x^*$ is a solution to the constrained optimization problem and $v$ is any tanget vector to the surface $g=0$ at $x^*$, then $\nabla f(x^*)=0$.
This assumes some regularity on $f$ and $g$ obviously but we will take that for granted. Now assume that $\nabla f \neq \lambda \nabla g $ at $x^*$, then there must exist some nonzero vector $v\perp \nabla g$ such that $\nabla f = \lambda\nabla g + v$. However, since $v\perp \nabla g$, it must be a tangent vector to the level surface $v=0$. If we take some curve $\alpha(s)$ passing through $x^*$ with tangent vector $v$, the directional derivative of $f$ along this curve will then be
$$
\frac{d}{d s}f(\alpha(s)) = \nabla f(\alpha(s))\cdot \alpha'(s).
$$
At $x^*$, this evaluates to
$$
\frac{d}{ds} f(\alpha(s)) = \nabla f(x^*)\cdot v = (\lambda \nabla g(x^*) + v)\cdot v = v\cdot v > 0.
$$
Therefore $f$ can increase along this curve and $x^*$ is not a solution to the optimization problem.
